# Filtering table with multiple filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter

I've got the following javascript which takes the input of a form element, and hides table rows that do not qualify with the search term.

```
<script>
    function wo_search(filter, column) {
        // Declare variables 
        var input, table, tr, td, i;
        input = document.getElementById("wo_search_type");
        table = document.getElementById("work_order");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[column];
            if (td) {
                if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The problem is, my table has 7 search terms, not just one. With my current code, only 1 filter works at a time. When one filter is selected, it will hide the correct elements in the table. As soon as a user selects a 2nd filter, the first filter is nullified, basically all of the data that was hidden by that filter is shown again before applying the filter from the 2nd term selected.

How can I make it so that all of the filters are applied together?

P.S

This is how the filter function is called based on what type of input it is, there are regular text inputs and select boxes.

Select boxes use `onchange="wo_search(this.value.toUpperCase(), 0)"`, the 2nd parameter being the table column id.

Input text uses `onkeyup="wo_search(this.value.toUpperCase(), 0)"`, the 2nd parameter being the table column id.

**EDIT:**
I don't think I was clear in my initial post, and I apologize for that, but there are 7 *different* inputs that I am trying to make the table filter for.

Basically, on the table, there is a row at the very top (Above the headers), that just contain an input box (Select or text input) that need to filter that specific column of the table.

Every column has it's own filter. Here is a screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

I'm thinking this may be easier to do with jquery, so jquery answers are also welcome.

Comment: you are going to need to keep active filters in an array or a collection to ensure they are not overwritten unless explicitly deleted. I unfortunately am not able to write any code for this at the moment but hopefully this gets you an idea.

Comment: @Jhecht That's the idea I had too, but I'm not really sure how I would do that unfortunately. I'm not much of a javascript developer :(

Comment: the question you need to ask yourself is what information would you need to apply multiple filters? Is it just the string, or do you gather other data from the DOM or `data-` attributes as well? Whatever you need goes into the array. Once something is added to the array you would loop through them, hiding anything that doesn't match (I'd probably use `array.filter` through each iteration), and then setting this new filter array to be the array that the next iteration searches through (instead of matching all of the components)

Comment: @Jhecht Hmm okay. I'll probably look into that a bit more tomorrow then. It's coming up to end of day for me and will be heading out soon. Thank you for the ideas :) I'll still be checking up here every once in a while for anyone who posts answers etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking in the comments of my original answer, here is what I got. Please check to see if this is what you need.

### Edit

I had forgotten to lower-case the text that was being tested against the filter, which caused some funky results.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var filters = [];
  //the array of current filters;
  var table_data = document.querySelectorAll('#filter-me tbody tr');
  //Gets all table rows in the filter me table

  //Adds an event listener to the filters list element
  document.querySelector('#filter-list').addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    if (!e.target.classList.contains('filter-item')) return false;
    var index = parseInt(e.target.getAttribute('data-index'));
    filters.splice(index, 1);
    update_filters();
    run_filters();
  })

  function value_change(column, e) {
    var action = false;
    //No action has been run
    
    if (e.type == 'keypress') {
      //if the action type is keypress, check to see if we have hit enter AND the value is not empty
      if (e.keyCode == 13 && this.value != '') {
        filters.push({
          column: column,
          filter: this.value.toLowerCase()
        });
        //reset the value
        this.value = '';
        //we have done something through this event, therefore we have action
        action = true;
      }
    } else if (e.type = 'change') {
      //If the event is change, simply push the column index + this select's value
      filters.push({
        column: column,
        filter: this.value.toLowerCase()
      });
      //Again, action is true
      action = true;
    }
    if (action) {
      //Since we have action, we need to update the filters list and run the filters against the table.
      update_filters();
      run_filters();
    }
  }

  //This line is sort of a mess:
  //create an empty array, call the slice method on it, binding it to the document.querySelectorAll('.column-filter') NodeList object
  //loop through each with the actual DOM node itself + it's index
  [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.column-filter')).forEach((filter, i) => {
    filter.addEventListener(filter.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'input' ? 'keypress' : 'change', value_change.bind(filter, i));
    //add the event listener to the correct type -- you may want to be more exact depending on your circumstances on this one to determine which event is added
    //Bind the value_change function to the element, but passing the first element as the index from the element of the nodelist.
  });

  function update_filters() {
    document.querySelector('#filter-list').innerHTML = "";
    //remove all elements;
    var els = filters.map((filter, i) => '<span class="filter-item" data-index="' + i + '">' + filter.filter + '</span>');
    //creates a fake span item here
    document.querySelector('#filter-list').innerHTML = els.join('');
    //joins everything with an empty space and sets the innerHTML to the result
  } // end update_filters

  function run_filters() {
    for (var i = 0, row, tds; row = table_data[i]; i++) {
      //get only the TD elements
      tds = row.querySelectorAll('td');
      //in order for a row to run, every filter must match.
      var pass = filters.every(filter => {
        return tds[filter.column].innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.filter) != -1;
        //for the filter to match, the TD element in the corresponding column must contain the text
      });
      row.style.display = pass ? '' : 'none'; //if pass, no display styles are added; otherwise, hide them.
    }

  } //end run_filters

});
```

```css
#filter-list {
  display: inline-block;
}

#filter-list span.filter-item {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: aqua;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#filter-list span.filter-item+span.filter-item {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#filter-list span.filter-item::after {
  content: 'x';
  margin-left: 4px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<table id="filter-me" class="table">
  <caption id="filter-list"></caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <select class="column-filter">
          <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
          <option value="lorem">Lorem</option>
          <option value="illum">Illum</option>
        </select>
      </th>
      <th><input type="search" placeholder="Filter" class="column-filter"></th>
      <th><input type="search" placeholder="Filter" class="column-filter"></th>
      <th><input type="search" placeholder="Filter" class="column-filter"></th>
      <th><input type="search" placeholder="Filter" class="column-filter"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Lorem, ipsum. <span class="arrow-up">&nbsp;</span></th>
      <th>Dolores, tempora?</th>
      <th>Tempore, soluta?</th>
      <th>Commodi, illum!</th>
      <th>Laudantium, debitis!</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
      <td>Magni aspernatur eveniet amet. Eos.</td>
      <td>Doloribus numquam at nisi fuga.</td>
      <td>Exercitationem libero saepe iusto labore!</td>
      <td>Quod, debitis. Hic, eius voluptates?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Excepturi aspernatur quia sequi labore.</td>
      <td>Ad tempore laudantium sed temporibus.</td>
      <td>Officia accusamus architecto perferendis quod?</td>
      <td>Laudantium facilis numquam quas iusto!</td>
      <td>Doloribus tenetur deleniti voluptatum alias.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ratione suscipit quis repudiandae ipsam!</td>
      <td>Repellendus blanditiis iure vel delectus.</td>
      <td>Sunt debitis voluptatum consectetur aliquam!</td>
      <td>Libero expedita odio maiores optio!</td>
      <td>Nam molestias delectus quam porro.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Earum delectus sint ab error?</td>
      <td>Dicta ipsam facilis optio aliquam?</td>
      <td>Blanditiis eligendi sit ad accusamus?</td>
      <td>Sequi laborum illo eos incidunt?</td>
      <td>Necessitatibus iure sequi eaque quam!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Illum aspernatur fuga laborum ratione!</td>
      <td>Maiores, excepturi! Dolorum, aspernatur mollitia.</td>
      <td>Labore corrupti itaque provident adipisci.</td>
      <td>Ipsum ducimus earum minus fuga.</td>
      <td>Necessitatibus rerum molestias autem libero.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nemo omnis similique labore minima!</td>
      <td>Dolore dolores saepe ea adipisci.</td>
      <td>Voluptate iusto in unde quas.</td>
      <td>Quod aperiam sit ut iusto.</td>
      <td>Quidem quisquam cupiditate dolor officiis.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Officia numquam aliquam qui nulla.</td>
      <td>Laboriosam repellendus soluta aliquid similique.</td>
      <td>Veritatis, neque porro? Quae, quia?</td>
      <td>Magnam vel autem ad blanditiis!</td>
      <td>Laboriosam, a. Sunt, suscipit deserunt!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Aspernatur iste saepe beatae nam.</td>
      <td>Ducimus quisquam corrupti quam inventore?</td>
      <td>Sit ullam minus possimus quidem!</td>
      <td>Officiis laborum laudantium veritatis et!</td>
      <td>Impedit dignissimos dolores maxime sequi.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Neque similique cum sequi unde!</td>
      <td>Voluptatibus, ad? Ullam, facilis cumque.</td>
      <td>Enim in magnam id illo!</td>
      <td>Ex nobis quidem voluptatem voluptate.</td>
      <td>Eligendi esse ipsa ipsam omnis!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Neque, fugit. Tempora, voluptates vel.</td>
      <td>Officia cupiditate dolores magni sunt?</td>
      <td>Eveniet tempore illo ipsa? Non.</td>
      <td>Possimus repellendus eligendi ipsam necessitatibus!</td>
      <td>Quisquam natus eos omnis ea.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Aliquam voluptas recusandae et animi?</td>
      <td>Quis distinctio officiis quisquam dolores.</td>
      <td>Repellendus suscipit vero delectus hic.</td>
      <td>Quae asperiores temporibus impedit quis.</td>
      <td>Temporibus ipsa quidem magnam odio.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Voluptatem optio quas nesciunt debitis!</td>
      <td>Hic mollitia alias laborum accusantium?</td>
      <td>Obcaecati eaque corrupti aperiam culpa!</td>
      <td>Voluptatum sequi sed numquam eos!</td>
      <td>Laborum exercitationem deleniti quaerat dolorem.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Modi nam asperiores totam excepturi.</td>
      <td>Quod ipsa dolorem magni labore.</td>
      <td>Qui quidem quod eum quasi!</td>
      <td>Explicabo, ut eveniet. Quos, nam?</td>
      <td>Harum fugit sequi blanditiis accusamus.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ullam dolores vel natus in?</td>
      <td>Dolor velit dolorum quos error!</td>
      <td>Obcaecati blanditiis natus aperiam esse.</td>
      <td>Consequatur quasi qui minima laboriosam.</td>
      <td>Voluptatum, et atque. Iste, earum?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Voluptate esse placeat doloribus hic?</td>
      <td>Dolorum velit ab incidunt quam.</td>
      <td>Laboriosam facere sed quia nisi.</td>
      <td>Saepe ex officia libero beatae?</td>
      <td>Ipsam ab distinctio assumenda itaque!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Perferendis facere natus accusantium ut.</td>
      <td>Ipsam possimus dolores corporis totam!</td>
      <td>Ab officia rerum tempora ipsum.</td>
      <td>Id, soluta neque! Voluptatibus, id.</td>
      <td>Eaque enim fugiat corporis velit!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Voluptatum cum atque eos quod.</td>
      <td>Esse corporis mollitia voluptatem ipsum.</td>
      <td>Corrupti unde inventore similique ad?</td>
      <td>Blanditiis dolorum molestiae minus tempore.</td>
      <td>Temporibus nihil doloremque quibusdam! Voluptatem!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Iste voluptates iusto facilis cum?</td>
      <td>At est necessitatibus architecto repellendus?</td>
      <td>Officia qui soluta veniam nemo.</td>
      <td>Nobis cupiditate officiis reiciendis possimus.</td>
      <td>Voluptatibus quidem assumenda adipisci quis.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Illum voluptatibus reprehenderit repellendus nostrum?</td>
      <td>Distinctio natus harum est nulla?</td>
      <td>Temporibus sit consequatur delectus ducimus.</td>
      <td>Veniam possimus qui fugiat temporibus.</td>
      <td>Delectus tenetur asperiores quasi perspiciatis.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quod atque ut doloribus libero?</td>
      <td>Animi assumenda praesentium alias accusantium!</td>
      <td>Labore ex optio eveniet architecto.</td>
      <td>Eaque delectus nemo fugiat dolorum.</td>
      <td>Atque, delectus. Obcaecati, saepe veritatis.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood a bit. There are 7 _different_ inputs that I need to use as filters.

Comment: Why 7 inputs? What makes it so you need that?

Comment: Every column has it's own filter. Here is a screenshot: https://ibb.co/hpYQqw (P.S I would have used the stackoverflow image site, but it's blocked here -.-)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton please take a look at the edited answer.

Comment: This appears to be exactly what I need! Now I just gotta convert it to work for my existing code. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey, there seems to be something wrong. In my code, when I select a filter, the whole table just clears every time. It shows no results. I made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1vtcxLnj/3/) but it actually doesn't work there at all for some reason. I'm really confused as to why

Comment: I changed some code around _and_ I changed the Javascript so that it was wrapped in the `<head>` instead of all being fired by the `onload` event. https://jsfiddle.net/1vtcxLnj/5/

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt to your requirement. So the below code will filter on filtered results. This means, when you enter something in first input, it would filter results based on that. Then, when you enter something in second input, it would filter results from the above results. So results once hidden, will never be considered in next set of searches.

In order to reset, clear all inputs / dropdowns, and you should be able to see all records again.

```js
$(".column-filter").on('change input', function() {
  var emptyFields = $('.column-filter').filter(function() {
    return $.trim(this.value) === "";
  });
  if (emptyFields.length == $(".column-filter").length) {
    $('table tbody tr').each(function() {
      $(this).show();
    });
  } else {
    var columnNumber = this.id;
    var enteredValue = $(this).val();
    $('table tbody tr:visible').each(function() {
      var str = $(this).find('td:eq(' + parseInt(columnNumber) + ')').text();
      if (str.toLowerCase().indexOf(enteredValue.toLowerCase()) == -1) {
        $(this).hide();
      } else {
        $(this).show();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
#filter-list {
  display: inline-block;
}

#filter-list span.filter-item {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: aqua;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#filter-list span.filter-item+span.filter-item {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#filter-list span.filter-item::after {
  content: 'x';
  margin-left: 4px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="filter-me" class="table">
  <caption id="filter-list"></caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <select id='0' class="column-filter">
          <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
          <option value="Lorem">Lorem</option>
          <option value="Illum">Illum</option>
        </select>
      </th>
      <th><input type="search" placeholder="Filter" class="column-filter" id="1"></th>
      <th><input type="search" placeholder="Filter" class="column-filter" id="2"></th>
      <th><input type="search" placeholder="Filter" class="column-filter" id="3"></th>
      <th><input type="search" placeholder="Filter" class="column-filter" id="4"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Lorem, ipsum. <span class="arrow-up">&nbsp;</span></th>
      <th>Dolores, tempora?</th>
      <th>Tempore, soluta?</th>
      <th>Commodi, illum!</th>
      <th>Laudantium, debitis!</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
      <td>Magni aspernatur eveniet amet. Eos.</td>
      <td>Doloribus numquam at nisi fuga.</td>
      <td>Exercitationem libero saepe iusto labore!</td>
      <td>Quod, debitis. Hic, eius voluptates?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Excepturi aspernatur quia sequi labore.</td>
      <td>Ad tempore laudantium sed temporibus.</td>
      <td>Officia accusamus architecto perferendis quod?</td>
      <td>Laudantium facilis numquam quas iusto!</td>
      <td>Doloribus tenetur deleniti voluptatum alias.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ratione suscipit quis repudiandae ipsam!</td>
      <td>Repellendus blanditiis iure vel delectus.</td>
      <td>Sunt debitis voluptatum consectetur aliquam!</td>
      <td>Libero expedita odio maiores optio!</td>
      <td>Nam molestias delectus quam porro.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Earum delectus sint ab error?</td>
      <td>Dicta ipsam facilis optio aliquam?</td>
      <td>Blanditiis eligendi sit ad accusamus?</td>
      <td>Sequi laborum illo eos incidunt?</td>
      <td>Necessitatibus iure sequi eaque quam!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Illum aspernatur fuga laborum ratione!</td>
      <td>Maiores, excepturi! Dolorum, aspernatur mollitia.</td>
      <td>Labore corrupti itaque provident adipisci.</td>
      <td>Ipsum ducimus earum minus fuga.</td>
      <td>Necessitatibus rerum molestias autem libero.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nemo omnis similique labore minima!</td>
      <td>Dolore dolores saepe ea adipisci.</td>
      <td>Voluptate iusto in unde quas.</td>
      <td>Quod aperiam sit ut iusto.</td>
      <td>Quidem quisquam cupiditate dolor officiis.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Officia numquam aliquam qui nulla.</td>
      <td>Laboriosam repellendus soluta aliquid similique.</td>
      <td>Veritatis, neque porro? Quae, quia?</td>
      <td>Magnam vel autem ad blanditiis!</td>
      <td>Laboriosam, a. Sunt, suscipit deserunt!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Aspernatur iste saepe beatae nam.</td>
      <td>Ducimus quisquam corrupti quam inventore?</td>
      <td>Sit ullam minus possimus quidem!</td>
      <td>Officiis laborum laudantium veritatis et!</td>
      <td>Impedit dignissimos dolores maxime sequi.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Neque similique cum sequi unde!</td>
      <td>Voluptatibus, ad? Ullam, facilis cumque.</td>
      <td>Enim in magnam id illo!</td>
      <td>Ex nobis quidem voluptatem voluptate.</td>
      <td>Eligendi esse ipsa ipsam omnis!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Neque, fugit. Tempora, voluptates vel.</td>
      <td>Officia cupiditate dolores magni sunt?</td>
      <td>Eveniet tempore illo ipsa? Non.</td>
      <td>Possimus repellendus eligendi ipsam necessitatibus!</td>
      <td>Quisquam natus eos omnis ea.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Aliquam voluptas recusandae et animi?</td>
      <td>Quis distinctio officiis quisquam dolores.</td>
      <td>Repellendus suscipit vero delectus hic.</td>
      <td>Quae asperiores temporibus impedit quis.</td>
      <td>Temporibus ipsa quidem magnam odio.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Voluptatem optio quas nesciunt debitis!</td>
      <td>Hic mollitia alias laborum accusantium?</td>
      <td>Obcaecati eaque corrupti aperiam culpa!</td>
      <td>Voluptatum sequi sed numquam eos!</td>
      <td>Laborum exercitationem deleniti quaerat dolorem.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Modi nam asperiores totam excepturi.</td>
      <td>Quod ipsa dolorem magni labore.</td>
      <td>Qui quidem quod eum quasi!</td>
      <td>Explicabo, ut eveniet. Quos, nam?</td>
      <td>Harum fugit sequi blanditiis accusamus.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ullam dolores vel natus in?</td>
      <td>Dolor velit dolorum quos error!</td>
      <td>Obcaecati blanditiis natus aperiam esse.</td>
      <td>Consequatur quasi qui minima laboriosam.</td>
      <td>Voluptatum, et atque. Iste, earum?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Voluptate esse placeat doloribus hic?</td>
      <td>Dolorum velit ab incidunt quam.</td>
      <td>Laboriosam facere sed quia nisi.</td>
      <td>Saepe ex officia libero beatae?</td>
      <td>Ipsam ab distinctio assumenda itaque!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Perferendis facere natus accusantium ut.</td>
      <td>Ipsam possimus dolores corporis totam!</td>
      <td>Ab officia rerum tempora ipsum.</td>
      <td>Id, soluta neque! Voluptatibus, id.</td>
      <td>Eaque enim fugiat corporis velit!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Voluptatum cum atque eos quod.</td>
      <td>Esse corporis mollitia voluptatem ipsum.</td>
      <td>Corrupti unde inventore similique ad?</td>
      <td>Blanditiis dolorum molestiae minus tempore.</td>
      <td>Temporibus nihil doloremque quibusdam! Voluptatem!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Iste voluptates iusto facilis cum?</td>
      <td>At est necessitatibus architecto repellendus?</td>
      <td>Officia qui soluta veniam nemo.</td>
      <td>Nobis cupiditate officiis reiciendis possimus.</td>
      <td>Voluptatibus quidem assumenda adipisci quis.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Illum voluptatibus reprehenderit repellendus nostrum?</td>
      <td>Distinctio natus harum est nulla?</td>
      <td>Temporibus sit consequatur delectus ducimus.</td>
      <td>Veniam possimus qui fugiat temporibus.</td>
      <td>Delectus tenetur asperiores quasi perspiciatis.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quod atque ut doloribus libero?</td>
      <td>Animi assumenda praesentium alias accusantium!</td>
      <td>Labore ex optio eveniet architecto.</td>
      <td>Eaque delectus nemo fugiat dolorum.</td>
      <td>Atque, delectus. Obcaecati, saepe veritatis.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```