# Filter table with multiple search strings (Vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript, html

- I'm trying to do this but instead to search within multiple columns of the same table: [https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp][1]
- In this example above, I would want not only want to filter by "name", but also by "Country".
- I found a similar post here, however it's for seven separate columns and there is no other vanilla JS code I could find: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47274028/filtering-table-with-multiple-filters?answertab=oldest#tab-top][2]
- I tried duplicating the loop (as shown below), but obviously that didn't work because the matches conflict with the first loop.

This is a little too advanced for me and I require a solution. Any help is appreciated.

```
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables 
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td1 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td1) {
      txtValue1 = td1.textContent || td1.innerText;
      if (txtValue1.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    } 
  }
  // this is what i've tried adding, but oviously, it conflicts with the first loop when matching
  for (j = 0; j < tr.length; j++) {
    td2 = tr[j].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td2) {
      txtValue2 = td2.textContent || td2.innerText;
      if (txtValue2.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[j].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[j].style.display = "none";
      }
    } 
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this modified function is of help to you. The basic change is that it does not search within individual table cells but within the concatenated text content of a complete table row.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");  
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
  
    var rowContent = tr[i].textContent;    
    rowContent = rowContent.replace(/[\s]+/g, ' ');
    //console.log(rowContent);    
  
    if (rowContent) {
      if (rowContent.toUpperCase().includes(filter)) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }  
    
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#myTable th, #myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
}

#myTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<h2>My Customers</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paris specialites</td>
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That works very well! It doesn't work for partial words, however that's a small price to pay and I won't be using columns with more than one word. For example, if you duplicate Alfreds' name with two different countries and then search "Alfred Sweden" only, it won't find it because the last name was omitted. I'm not sure if there's a way around this for the next person seeing this, but for me I'll only be using single words so it doesn't affect me. I'll give you your points. You saved me a lot of time. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Split the search string by space and filter the columns for each word. You can use the same `for()` for both columns. Try this code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var src, input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase().trim().split(' ');
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  for (j = 0; j < filter.length; j++) {
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    src = filter[j].trim();
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
      td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
      td2 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
      if (src.length>1 && td && td2) {
        txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
        txtValue2 = td2.textContent || td2.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(src) > -1 || txtValue2.toUpperCase().indexOf(src) > -1) {
          tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }       
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, however it doesn't work because you can't put more than one search string (as my title says), in the search field to match. Go to the link below, replace with your code and also put two "Alfreds" in different countries. Then search for "Alfreds Futterkiste Germany", it won't match it...  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_table

Comment: Thank you. It's almost perfect and I thought of that too with nested loops and if statement. However, there's a bit of a hick-up. For example, type-in "Alfreds Futterkiste G". Notice how when adding the G in the end, it screws things up. When having many string searches, the problems could pile-up. Also do you think there could be a cleaner way if I have 10 columns to search in?

Comment: I put `src.length>1` to search for words with 2+ letters. A cleaner way for 10 columns, no idea.

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort. But this unfortunately, I noticed on second inspection that this doesn't work at all. For example, type: "Alfreds Futterkiste Germany". You will see that it doesn't filter properly and rather adds more results. Not really a "filter" per say... Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Okay i thought differently my mistake you can separate search function to do easy work and you can try i have modified my code with concatenation of string.

```
function myFunction() {
 var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
   search(input, filter, table, tr);

}


function search(input, filter, table, tr){
 for (i = 1; i < tr.length ; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    var concat='';
    for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
     txtValue = td[j].textContent || td[j].innerText;
     concat += txtValue+' ';
     }
     console.log(concat);
    if (td) {

      if (concat.toUpperCase().search(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";

      }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: While your contribution is appreciated, you should remember to explain your answer.

Comment: Okay i will remember next time when i will do my contribution.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, however it doesn't work because you can't put more than one search string (as my title says), in the search field to match. Go to the link below, replace with your code and also put two "Alfreds" in different countries. Then search for "Alfreds Futterkiste Germany", it won't match it... http://w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_table